# AWS API Gateway setting required headers - does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I create an api gateway and have included custom header fields like correlationId as required header inputs to its endpoint. When I deployed the APIGW, it does not work. I tried testing it, created a request with correlationId missing in the header, but no error was shown that the particular header field is missing. Same thing for format validation. Is there anything else I need to do to enable this validation?

I checked AWS APIGW docs and it said there should be validation once it has been set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

1. Make sure you have created REST API (Protocol: REST)
2. In the API Gateway console, select your API.
3. In the left-hand navigation pane, choose "Resources".
4. Select the resource and the method for which you want to validate headers (something like GET - Method execution).
5. Under the selected resource, choose "Method Request" and click "Edit".
6. Under **Method request settings** select **"Validate query string parameters and headers"** from **"Request validator"** dropdown.
7. Expand the "HTTP Request Headers" section and **add header with flag "Required"**.

Safe changes, redeploy API and after some small time you will see:

```
 {"message": "Missing required request parameters: [correlationId]"}
```

for requests which doesn't have header `correlationId`

Comment: hey thanks a lot it worked. But how about format validation? is this out of scope of APIGW?

Comment: There is no option to configure it there